# css not working on header tag

Tags: html, css

I have this html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<p></p>
<h2>Meeting the Old Guard  </h2>
<p>I was shot in Vietnam by an old man. .</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and this css stylesheet named test.css

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 2cm;
    color: #f0f;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-left: max-width: 1400px; }
}

h2 {
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;
}

p {
    color: #fff;

}
```

The body tag specifies a magenta color. The h2 tag and the p tag specify white. However, the h2 is rendered magenta and the paragraph white. Why doesnt the header render white?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an extra bracket on your body tag

```
body {
width: 100%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: 2cm;
color: #f0f;
background-color: #000;
margin-left: max-width: 1400px; }
```

} <----Your extra bracket is messing things up

Check out https://jsfiddle.net/bryanseven/vvw3k7to/ to see it working correctly.

Comment: Thank you. such a stupid mistake on my part to even bother the folks here. It doesnt even have the dignity to be called a mistake.

Comment: Man that happens to everyone. I've spent hours wondering why Ive had an error only to realize its something silly. Sometimes you just need another set of eyes

Answer (score 3):

You are missing starting body tag here.

It should be :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<p></p>
<h2>Meeting the Old Guard  </h2>
<p>I was shot in Vietnam by an old man. .</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Also you have an extra ending bracket bracket in your css of body.

Comment: "//added" is the comment.

Comment: I added extra comment //added which I just removed. Now try and also remove one extra ending bracket in css body.